# Devise User Stack Level Too Deep Error - Possibly due to this added Username funcitonality

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, devise

When I try to access `current_user` via Devise...

```
def current_user 
    @user =  User.find(current_user.id)
    @user
end
```

and render some of their attributes in JSON via this RABL template...

```
object @user
attributes :email, :username
```

I get this error...

```
SystemStackError at /api/current_user
stack level too deep
```

I think the error is due to something within this User model, which I modified slightly to add in a Username field.  I followed [Devise's instructions here](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To%3a-Allow-users-to-sign-in-using-their-username-or-email-address) to add this functionality...

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :token_authenticatable, :encryptable, :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable

  attr_accessible :login, :username, :email, :password, :password_confirmation, :remember_me

  has_many :cart_items, dependent: :destroy

  # Virtual attribute for authenticating by either username or email
  # This is in addition to a real persisted field like 'username'
  attr_accessor :login

  def self.find_first_by_auth_conditions(warden_conditions)
      conditions = warden_conditions.dup
      if login = conditions.delete(:login)
        where(conditions).where(["lower(username) = :value OR lower(email) = :value", { :value => login.downcase }]).first
      else
        where(conditions).first
      end
  end

end
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are calling current_user from within current_user...

```
def current_user 
   @user =  User.find(current_user.id)

                          ^^^^
```

It then calls itself, which then calls itself again, and again... until you get the Stack Overflow

I'm not sure you you seem to need to re-write the current_user method.
afaik Devise already does that for you.
Can you show me where in that tutorial it says to rewrite `def current_user`?

Comment: Yikes, how obvious was this.  I just changed the action's name and had no problems.  Thanks Taryn :)

Comment: we all scratch our heads over that kind of thing from time to time :)
Sometimes you just need a fresh pair of eyes.